# Log forging with the request object

Tags: java, logging, log-forging

I am dealing with the log forging issue for the code :

log.error("Request: " + req.getRequestURL() + " raised " +  exception);

This element’s value (req.getRequestURL())  flows through the code without being properly
sanitized or validated, and is eventually used in writing an audit log in handleError

I tried to remove the \n\r characters but with no success.

I have gone through different sites searching for the same but did not find the helpful content. 
Can anyone please explain the solution for this or a small guide to fix it.

Thanks

Comment: How did you try to remove the \n\r characters?

Comment: req.getRequestURL() is returning StringBuffer so first converted into the string and then called replace() method on it.   String sb = req.getRequestURL().toString();
  
  sb = sb.replace("\n\r", "") ;

Comment: Are you forgetting URL encoding?

Comment: Hi Kayaman 
Do u mean : 
URLEncoder.encode(sb)  ; 

I had searched for this and referd the site 
http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-encode-a-url-string-or-form-parameter-in-java/

but that code was rejected by my  higher member :( :(

Answer (score 1):

Use ESAPI library to protect log forging attack. Refer to 
http://www.jtmelton.com/2010/09/21/preventing-log-forging-in-java/ for code reference.

```
String clean = message.replace( '\n', '_' ).replace( '\r', '_' );
if ( ESAPI.securityConfiguration().getLogEncodingRequired() ) {
    clean = ESAPI.encoder().encodeForHTML(message);
    if (!message.equals(clean)) {
        clean += " (Encoded)";
    }
}
```